# TYPO3 and tx_news, hide nontranslated news

Tags: localization, typo3, typoscript

I have a site which is multilingual (dk, de and uk)
In my list of news i have some news that are only in the default language (DK).
They should not be shown in the English and German version of the site.

Shouldn't this work out-of-the-box?

I have this in my TypoScript template

```
config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> config.sys_language_mode = strict

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/KnownProblems/Index.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue but when in strict mode my media files aren't beeing shown in an article only in i.e. german as long as its not the default language. Translating an article with an original link does show the media though.

Answer (score 0):

Language behavior changed in every Typo3 version a lot.  As the core does every query and language overylay handling please check latest stable version and / or file a bug in core issue tracker